# How to return a value from a coroutine using co_return?

Tags: c++, asynchronous, c++20, coroutine

In the code below, I am trying to return from a coroutine std :: vector . The problem is that only the result of the  `std::vector<int> get_return_object()` is returned from the coroutine.

When the co_return statement is executed, method `void return_value(std::vector<int>&& value)` is called, which fills the vector returned by method `get_return_object()`. But the vector from `get_return_object()` is returned by value and it doesn't work. When I try to do so

```
std::vector<int> return_value(std::vector<int>&& value){
    return value
}
```

An empty vector is also returned from the coroutine, although value is not empty.

How to return a value from a coroutine without wrapping it in a Task containing a promise_object?

exemple:

```
#include "coroutine"
#include "iostream"
struct Promise {
    std::vector<int> vec;
    std::vector<int> get_return_object() {
        return vec;
    }

    std::suspend_never initial_suspend() {
        return {};
    }

    std::suspend_never final_suspend() {
        return {};
    }

    void return_void() {}

    void return_value(std::vector<int>&& value){
        vec = std::move(value);
    }

    void unhandled_exception() { std::terminate(); }
};

template<typename... Args>
struct std::coroutine_traits<std::vector<int>, Args...>{
    using promise_type = Promise;
};

class Caller{
public:
    std::vector<int> call();
};

std::vector<int> Caller::call() {
    co_return std::vector<int>{1, 2, 3, 4};
}

int main(){
    Caller c;
    auto vec =  c.call();
    std::cout << vec.size();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Well the first problem is your specialization of coroutine traits does not depend on any user provided types, so your program is ill formed.  Add the implicit parameter of this to it.  ;)

Comment: Second, replace "But the vector from get_return_object() is returned by value and it doesn't work." the "it doesn't work" with a full description of what happens, and how that does not match what you want.  "it doesn't work" isn't sufficient.

Comment: "The problem is that only the result of the std::vector<int> get_return_object() is returned from the coroutine." wait, what?  How is this a problem?

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont, The problem is that the value returned by get_return_object () cannot be refilled by the return_value function, since it is returned by value. And I don’t know how to return the result from the coroutine not through get_return_object.

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont," Add the implicit parameter of this to it." How to do it?

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont, I don't understand how to use the return_value function

Comment: Refilled?  I believe you are confused, enough that I do not even know what this code is supposed to do, and you are still not saying what "it does not work" means.  Write code.  Compile it.  Be explicit about what does not work (complie or runtime error message, incorrect output: but be explicit, not "it is wrong").  Describe what you want the correct output to be.

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont, 
"it doesn't work" means that instead of a vector with the values ​​{1, 2, 3, 4} passed as an input parameter to the co_return operator, an empty vector is returned from the coroutine.

Comment: do yourself a favor and use something written. currently there are about 3-4 mature libraries to pick from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`std::vector<int>` is not an awaitable type, so it can't usefully be the return object of a coroutine.

If you [add some tracing](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/73526ebd4ab39f30), you can see the order of operations going wrong.

`get_return_object` needs to return something that can be given a `std::vector<int>` later. E.g. if all users of `Promise` never suspend:

```
struct Promise {
    struct result {
        std::future<std::vector<int>> fut;
        operator std::vector<int>() { return fut.get(); }
    };
    
    std::promise<std::vector<int>> prom;

    result get_return_object() {
        std::cout << "get_return_object" << std::endl;
        
        return { prom.get_future() };
    }

    std::suspend_never initial_suspend() {
        std::cout << "initial_suspend" << std::endl;
        return {};
    }

    std::suspend_never final_suspend() {
        std::cout << "final_suspend" << std::endl;
        return {};
    }

    void return_void() {}

    void return_value(std::vector<int>&& value){
        std::cout << "return_value" << std::endl;
        prom.set_value(std::move(value));
    }

    void unhandled_exception() { std::terminate(); }
};
```

Comment: Please show me how to release this in code

Comment: That is, in order to get the result of the promise, do I need to call the coroutine via co_await, or create a method in the promise class that returns the result?

Comment: `main` cannot be a coroutine.

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont The part where I `co_await`ed in main, or explaining that `co_await vec` was a non-starter if `vec` is `std::vector<int>`?

Comment: @Caleth The OP's code has no `co_await vec` in it.  A coroutine is a kind of function, and a function returning a `std::vector` can be a coroutine.  It must have another parameter (including this for a member function), but it can be a coroutine.